# Как сделать замену частей страницы с помощью razor?

Tags: c#, razor

Как сделать замену(и добавление) частей страницы с помощью razor?

На странице открывается кнопка1

```
-
-кнопка1->
```

При нажатии на кнопку1 появляется ниже кнопка2

```
-
-кнопка1
--кнопка2->
```

При нажатии на кнопку2 появляется ниже кнопка3

```
-
-кнопка1
--кнопка2
---кнопка3
```

Comment: Это обычно делают с помощью JavaScript. Зачем здесь делать аж целый запрос, чтобы задействовать Razor? Но если совсем надо, то может помочь [ASP.NET AJAX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-implement-dynamic-partial-page-updates-with-aspnet-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <style>
 #cImp2 {
    display: none;
        }
 #cImp3 {
    display: none;
        }
 </style>
 
  
  
  
 <input type="submit" id="cImp1" value="Кнопка1" />
  <input type="submit" id="cImp2" value="Кнопка2" />
   <input type="submit" id="cImp3" value="Кнопка3" />
   
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $("#cImp1").click(function () {
   $("#cImp2").css("display","block");
   });
   
   $("#cImp2").click(function () {
   $("#cImp3").css("display","block");
   });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

или так , если кнопки пойдут друг за другом

```html
<style>
 .cImput {
    display: none;
        }
 #cImp1 {
    display: block;
        }
 </style>
 
  
  
  
 <input class="cImput"type="submit" id="cImp1" value="Кнопка1" />
 <input class="cImput" type="submit" id="cImp2" value="Кнопка2" />
 <input class="cImput" type="submit" id="cImp3" value="Кнопка3" />
 <input class="cImput" type="submit" id="cImp4" value="Кнопка4" /> 
 <input class="cImput" type="submit" id="cImp5" value="Кнопка5" />
 <input class="cImput" type="submit" id="cImp6" value="Кнопка6" /> 
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(".cImput").click(function () {
   var u = ($(this).attr("id"));
   var a = "cImp" + (parseInt(u.slice(4)) + 1);
   if (parseInt(u.slice(4)) < 6){
   $("#"+a).css("display","block");
   }
   });
   
   
   </script>
```